# How to resolve problem "too many clients already" with liquibase in spring tests?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

When running all tests in my spring-boot application I get liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already. This exception throws in the last few tests
Maybe someone knows how to manage connections in liquibase without pool creating?
There is no configured pool in the project.
All queries to DB by 'extends CrudRepository'

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients
>   already .

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Liquibase uses one connection. There could be another problem. What is your setup of postgresql db?

try to select all active connections and see where they come from:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
```

show number of maxConnections

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'max_connections';
```

or

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

if it's too low, you can increase it in `postgresql.conf` and restart the db

Comment: I've done it several times already. This is no way out. Thanks.

Comment: so maybe you have connection leaks in your tests

Comment: Should not be. Looks like for each test, connections creates, but do not close.

Comment: So what is the final solution? Can we do some settings to close the connections which are idle?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party here, but I had the same issue.  I've solved it by autowiring the `dataSource` into my test like so:

```java
@Autowired
protected DataSource dataSource;
protected HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;
```

Then in the before step, cast the `dataSource` to `hikariDataSource`:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {
   hikariDataSource = (HikariDataSource) dataSource;
}
```

Then in the after step I closed the `hikariDataSource`:

```java
@After
public void teardown() {
if (hikariDataSource != null) {
    hikariDataSource.close();
}
```